# How to make autocomplete=off working in google chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome

Some people made Chrome not respecting `autocomplete=off`. So it is hard to make forms like: add new user or add new contact, because it gets always (auto) filled with WRONG data.

Now I use something like:

```css
input.password {
  text-security: disc !important;
  -webkit-text-security: disc !important;
  -moz-text-security: disc !important;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

But it may not work in other browsers.

Is there any correct method to override this Google Chrome default action?

Comment: I think the argument is already treated here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill

Comment: Stupid "programmers" from google make it all not working again. So, I am asking question again. Or maybe we should abadon google chrome  as it is not respecting standards, and inform users to do the same.

Comment: But you are talking about the plugin of Chrome called **Addresses & payment methods** right? You can disable it. But you can't disable in your customers computer. That's an extra feature a browser offers, you can't stop it.